# is there a way to define the sequence id in @OneToOne middle entity?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to configure the association table's identifier and its sequence generator, similar to what was done for tables A and B using the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation? As seen in the examples below, Hibernate does not perform the retrieval of the next identifier (`nextval`), and consequently, it does not assign the id value to the association table.

[Association draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1bxt.png)

**SQL insertion generated by Hibernate:**

```sql
insert into
            ASSOCIATION_TABLE
            (ID_TABLE_A, ID_TABLE_B) 
        values
            (123, 456);
```

***Error report***

```
ORA-01400: it is not possible to insert NULL in ("user"."ASSOCIATION_TABLE"."ID_ASSOCIATION")
```

***Entity A***

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
public class TableA {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_TABLE_A", length = 20)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TABLE_A_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "TABLE_A_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "TABLE_A_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ASSOCIATION_TABLE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TABLE_A", referencedColumnName = "ID_TABLE_A"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TABLE_B", referencedColumnName = "ID_TABLE_B")
    )
    private TableB b;

    // getters and setters
}
```

***Entity B***

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
public class TableB {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_TABLE_B", length = 20)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TABLE_B_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "TABLE_B_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "TABLE_B_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b")
    private TableA a;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: No. If you want that you will have to model the many-to-many as an additional entity with its own ID.

Comment: From a data normalisation perspective it seems odd to do a OneToOne with an association table. Typically this is a many-to-many relationship (or you could have modelled it with a single (foreign) key in tabelA or tableB  Are you sure you have reasons to do it like this?